# Trying to make directive wrapping UI Bootstraps typeahead to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm wrapping UI Bootstraps typeahead in a directive and have trouble accessing `$viewValue` in the template.
I want to be able to call the `getAutocompleteList` function specified in the typeahead-attribute in the template with the current `$viewValue`. Currently the value is always undefined.

In my actual application `getAutocompleteList` makes an ajax call to the server where the are millions of records to choose from. This example is just to show the problem.

I've also made a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nwnqjScDnuSHXfX9PK5g?p=preview)

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,list) {
  $scope.modell = {};
  $scope.modell.grupp = {label: "Your State", placeholder:'Write state name', namn: "aaa"};
  $scope.modell.getAutocompleteList = function(namn) {return list.getList(namn); };
});

app.directive('myautocomplete', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      modell: "=",
      getAutocompleteList: "&"
    },
    templateUrl: 'skriv.html',
  }
});

app.factory('list', function($q){
  return {
    getList: function(search) {
      console.log(search);
      states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
      var result = states;
      if(search) {
        result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
          if(states[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === 0){
            result.push(states[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      else {result = states}
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(result);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

**Html file**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div myautocomplete modell="modell.grupp" get-autocomplete-list="modell.getAutocompleteList($viewValue)"></div>
</body>
```

**template - skriv.html**

```
<div>
  <span>{{modell.label}}</span>
  <input id="inputautocomplete" type="text" ng-model="valtId" placeholder="{{modell.placeholder}}" typeahead="state for state in getAutocompleteList($viewValue)" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this working after several hours. This is what I did.

- I used $parse service to be able to controll what was sended to my getAutocompleteList method by changing the context.
  It doesn't work with isolated scopes so I changed to a shared scope.
- I added a method where I call the parsed expression and change the context.

  ```
  app.directive('myautocomplete', function() {
    return {
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'skriv.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var hamtaLista = $parse(attrs.getAutocompleteList);
        scope.hamta = function(varde) { return hamtaLista(scope,{viewValue: varde});     };
      }  
    }
  });
  ```

I adapted the template since I no longer had an isolated scope. Here I call the new method that changes the context. When calling this method I send a parameter with the $viewValue. This is the value that gets send to my getAutocompleteList method.

```
    <div>
      <span>{{modell.grupp.label}}</span>
      <input id="inputautocomplete" type="text" ng-model="modell.grupp.state" placeholder="{{modell.grupp.placeholder}}" typeahead="state for state in hamta($viewValue)" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

Finally I also changed the declaration of the directive in the html. Just to clarify the difference between viewValue and $viewValue.

```
<div myautocomplete modell="modell.grupp" get-autocomplete-list="modell.getAutocompleteList(viewValue)"></div>
```

This is my working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nz3SSerUjDIcmzqX6UdH?p=preview)